# Get right context(this) in callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datacontext

I try to call a function in a callback and do something with the  class context(this). But when calling the callback function, it doesn't have any context. `this` is undefined. I tried a few things with `bind(self)` but didn't work out.

```
export class AppComponent { 
    connect(call,callb){
            var self=this
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.responseType=responseType
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/"+call, true);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    callb(xhttp.response).bind(self);                
                }
            };
            xhttp.send(null)
    }


    buildXML(response){
            console.log(this) //prints undefined, should print AppComponent or something
    }

    this.connect("someCall",this.buildXML)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `callb.bind(self)(xhttp.response)`? ie. bind before you call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `bind()` the function context, then invoke it.

```
callb.bind(self)(xhttp.response);
```

instead of

```
callb(xhttp.response).bind(self);
```

Comment: absolutely right... thanks a lot! Sometimes it's really that easy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a fat arrow function as a callback to get correct context:

```
() => {}
```